# Word for standard software patterns

Tags: communication

I can't remember this word that describes common standards and practices in the language that one is programming in. For instance:

in Java:
Putting curly braces on the same line:

```
public void x() {
}
```

vs

```
public void x()
{
}
```

Is an example of this word I am searching for. It's fairly common in the online community. It's similar to `pragmatic`, `ubiquitous`, and `common`, but it's a bit more fancy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This would typically be called a "coding style", "coding standard" or "coding convention" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions), and may vary from project to project - it's not *necessarily* a language thing. In the PHP world, for example, these are defined by a "PHP Standard Recommendation" or PSR. https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Answer (score 0):

The word I was searching for is `idiomatic`